# Using git-svn with existing svn project

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I'm currently working on a project that has a svn repository. I'm used to git and love the way it allows me to have a local repository, so I would like to use git-svn with this project.

I would like to know how to use git-svn from a svn project already in my computer. Do I really need to make a clone and start from there? Or can I just do something like `git svn init` in the current project folder and proceed from there?

Also I would like to know about any big issues using git-svn, since this is a serious project and I shouldn't mess around with the repo.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git-svn work really great. But can be slow to start, because check all revision from your svn repository to create new one on your git repository.

You need start with clone or init + fetch. The clone launch init and fetch command.

After your first fetch, a `git svn rebase` is great to be update.

Comment: Hi, if I understand you correctly I have to clone my repo again with git-svn? There's no way to init git-svn on an existing directory?